# Failed to compile JSP due to this code

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to involve myself learning JSP today.

This is the JSP code that's i'm testing around:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%! Queries x = new Queries(); %>
<TABLE BORDER=2>
<%

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        %>
        <TR>
        <TD>Number</TD>
        <TD><%= i+1 %></TD>
        </TR>
        <%
    }
%>
</TABLE>
             <form action="parser">
            <p>Name:<input type="text" name="userName"></p>
            <p>Password:<input type="text" name="passWord"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="login"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem lies here when i try to initialize :

```
<%! Queries x = new Queries(); %>
```

The class is in my package itself.

**Queries.java**

```
public class Queries {

 public String RetrieveNickName()  {
         Database conn = new Database(); 
         String sql = "SELECT nickname from user where uid = 1";
         String x = conn.querySQL(sql).toString();
         return x;
       } 
}
```

I received this error when i try to run it.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: 


type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Queries cannot be resolved to a type
13:         <title>JSP Page </title>
14:     </head>
15:     <body>
16:         <%! Queries x = new Queries(); %>
17: <TABLE BORDER=2>
18: <%
19:     


An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Queries cannot be resolved to a type
13:         <title>JSP Page </title>
14:     </head>
15:     <body>
16:         <%! Queries x = new Queries(); %>
17: <TABLE BORDER=2>
18: <%
19:     


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXMvc.jpg

Comment: And how have you added `Queries` to your project? Because the error seems pretty clear to me; is it in a package? And how are you building / deploying?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, it's not under my web inf . I'm building via tomcat7 neatbean IDE.

Comment: It would have to be under web-inf/classes folder, or packaged as a jar and added to web-inf/lib.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, i've attached the screenshot via imgur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you imported the class first. `<%@ page import="<your package>.Queries" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not imported the package:
`<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"% import="packageName.Queries">`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be is the default package.The default package is invisible to server.so you should put it inside any named package,something similar to this

```
/WEB-INF/classes/MyPackage/Queries.claass
```